# Combining OpenGL and Blender Render (For Lightsabers)

Tags: rendering, node-editor, opengl

I'm working on another lightsaber video.  For the clashes this time, I've decided to utilize a lens flare pack by cfirwin3 [here](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/76172) and it's super awesome. However, it appears that they only render properly when I push that OpenGL render button down at the bottom of the 3D viewport screen (I don't really know anything about OpenGL). That's all fine and dandy, but can I use this output in the Node compositor? More importantly, can I use this output and integrate it with the renderlayers I have for the lightsabers?

I realize I could render the lens flares as an entirely separate video but I would prefer not to because the clashes are just a small portion of the video and most of the animation would be black.

Thanks.

Can only be rendered as seen if OpenGL is used (as far as I know). Can't be used directly in compositor from here:

[image]

And how do I combine it with my lightsabers on other layers:
[image]

I can composite the lightsabers:
[image]

And this is the sort of look I'm going for (credit to Maxwell Swet):
[image]